# Toggling a grid in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to display a dojo grid on click of a button.
This is the function that gets called once the button is clicked:

```
        function initAndDisplayDataGtrid(){

            var dataStore = new dojox.data.CsvStore({url: path});

            var chartDivNode=dojo.create("div");
            chartDivNode.setAttribute("id","chartDivId");
            chartDivNode.setAttribute("class", "toggle_container");

            var grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
            query: {},
            store: dataStore,
            autoWidth:"2",
            autoHeight:"5",
            columnReordering:true,
            structure: chartLayout,
            noDataMessage: localizedLabel.NO_RESULTS

        });
            grid.placeAt("chartDivId");
            grid.startup();
        }
```

But this is throwing an error: `TypeError: _3d6 is null` when I check in firebug.

Not sure what might be null at this point.

Comment: Did you append the `chartDivNode` to the body(or other rendered element)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have provided, you dynamically create a new  element that you then call "chartDivId".  You then execute a "placeAt" call to place your newly created grid as a child of "chartDivId".  However, the placeAt call searches the document and won't find "chartDivId" because it has not yet been attached to the document as a whole.

See the following Dojo documentation on how to create a new element and insert it into the page.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/create.html

It seems that there are parameters to the dojo.create() method.  The 1st is the type of element to create, the 2nd are any options you may wish to pass ... but the 3rd is where within the document the new element should be attached.